# Cannot declare List property in the JPA @Entity class. It says 'Basic' attribute type should not be a container

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA `@Entity class Place`, with some properties holding some information about a place, such as name of place, description, and URLs of some images.

For the URLs of images, I declare a `List<Link>` in my entity.

[image]

However, I am getting this error:

> `Basic attribute type should not be a container.`

I tried to remove `@Basic`, but the error message is still there. Why does it shows this error?

Comment: Any basic JPA(2) docs will say that a List of Strings requires an ElementCollection annotation. As for why you refer to Python docs when using Java ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems not have impact on GAE since I can run the app and store data into storage. I guess it's a bug in IntelliJ IDEA and you can simply ignore it.

[image]

Comment: It is not so a bug - if an entity holds a list of another entities, this means "one to many" relation, not "basic" field. If you add @OneToMany annotation, error in IDE will disappear.

Comment: @Hesam I also think that this answer is really wrong.. and IDE bug has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 53):

You can also use `@ElementCollection`:

```
@ElementCollection
private List<String> tags;
```

Comment: I used it but tags are not stored into DB

Comment: Maybe you need to declare a @Column(columnDefinition = "String[]"). In my case, I have to implement that way in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 39):

You are most likely missing an *association mapping* (like `@OneToMany`) and/or `@Entity` annotation(s).

I had a same problem in:

```
@Entity
public class SomeFee {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private List<AdditionalFee> additionalFees;
    //other fields, getters, setters..
}

class AdditionalFee {
    @Id
    private int id;
    //other fields, getters, setters..
}
```

and `additionalFees` was the field causing the problem.

What I was missing and what helped me are the following:

1. `@Entity` annotation on the generic type argument (`AdditionalFee`) class;
2. `@OneToMany` (or any other type of association that fits particular business case) annotation on the `private List<AdditionalFee> additionalFees;` field.

So, the working version looked like this:

```java
@Entity
public class SomeFee {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany
    private List<AdditionalFee> additionalFees;
    //other fields, getters, setters..
}
    
@Entity
class AdditionalFee {
    @Id
    private int id;
    //other fields, getters, setters..
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Or you can mark it as `@Transient` if it doesn't exist on DB table.

```
@Transient
private List<String> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: worked for me with private Set<String>. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Change `@basic` to `@OneToMany` for List types

Answer (score 2):

As the message says, `@Basic` should not be used for containers (e.g. Java collections). It is only to be used for a limited list of basic types. Remove the `@Basic` annotation on that field.

If, as you say in the question, the error message is still there, you might need to try the following steps in order:

1. Save the file
2. Close and reopen the file
3. Clean and rebuild the project
4. Restart the IDE

(these are generic steps, which I use when an IDE is generating a compilation error that obviously makes no sense.)

Comment: Thanks Robin, but unfortunately didn't work :( I'm trying to figuring out what's the problem. Error message will be gone by removing "@Entity(name = "Book")", however, I don't think it's the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen when your class is missing its @Entity annotation. When you get weird warnings like these, sometimes it helps to try and compile and see if the compiler complains.

Answer (score 0):

> 'Basic' attribute type should not be a container

This error occurs when you declare an existing entity as an attribute in the current Entity without declaring the relationship type which could be either of the JPA relationships.
[Detailed Article on JPA relationships](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

Check and specify whether it is `@OneToMany @OneToOne @ManyToMany`
as per the requirement and replace with @Basic