# foreach not applicable to type 'java.lang.String'

Tags: java

I am trying to insert items in a list in a database as single values in rows.  How can I loop through the payload sent and insert all the items into individual rows? I have tried to look for examples no luck. I cannot loop and insert the values in the database.

this is the payload

```
{"labsigned":["234568","234567","2345678","2344556","12335677","2345677","234556","234545"]}
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/labreport/createrordispatched", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createDispatched(@RequestBody Dispatched dispatched){
    if(labDashboardService.createDispatched(dispatched)) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(true);
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(false);
}
```

My Service

```
public boolean createDispatched(Dispatched dispatched) {
    List<Dispatched> newTickets = new ArrayList<>();

    dispatched.setCreatedBy(getCurrentUserEmail());
    dispatched.setDateCreated(System.currentTimeMillis());

    for(String labsigned:dispatched.getlabsigned()){
        Dispatched ticket = new Dispatched(
                dispatched.getCreatedBy(),
                dispatched.getDateCreated(),
                labsigned
        );
        newTickets.add(ticket);
    }
    dispatchedRepository.saveAll(newTickets);
    return true;
}
```

My Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DISPATCHED")
public class Dispatched {
    private String id;
    private String labsigned;
    private Long dateCreated;
    private String createdBy;

    public Dispatched(){}
    public Dispatched(String createdBy, Long dateCreated, String labsigned){
        this.labsigned = rorlabsigned;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;

    }
//getters and setters
```

the line that is giving me an error

```
  for(String rorlabsigned:dispatched.getRorlabsigned())
```

How should I set my entity to accept arrays?

Comment: `dispatched.getlabsigned()` returns `labsigned` property of `Dispatched` which is String and not an iterable object. What is expected type there? It's confusing to me that you're trying to create list of new tickets from a single Dispatched object.

Comment: It expects an Iterable object as the payload comes as `{"labsigned":["234568","234567","2345678","2344556","12335677","2345677","234556","234545"]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your `labsigned`  field as Set or use `String.split` like:

```
for(String rorlabsigned : dispatched.getRorlabsigned().split(",")) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your getter `dispatched.getRorlabsigned()` does not return a `Collection`. It returns a single `String` instead. You can't loop over a `String` using `foreach`. I guess you need a `Set<String>` there. Try to refactor that part of your code.

Comment: Hi @Marcus, I need to `Set<String>` where? Thank you for your response

Comment: `private Set<String> labsigned;` in the model

Comment: I end up getting `Basic' attribute type should not be a container`

Comment: try using @ElementCollection annotation above. You can check out thread here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059451/cannot-declare-list-property-in-the-jpa-entity-class-it-says-basic-attribute

Comment: Gives me another error Could not determine type for: `java.util.Set, at table: BDISPATCHED, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(labsigned)]`

Comment: How experienced are you in Java, Hibernate/JPA, and JSON? Maybe it would make more sense to start with a tutorial for one or more of the involved technologies to raise your understanding, instead of just throwing code snippets around?