# Spring Boot doesn't increment auto-generated id with type long

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, api

I'm creating a collection with a Long id type called idPallet which should be incremented.

*Pallet.java (collection)*

```
package com.example.ShippingTest.collections;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Pallet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "pallet_seq",strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "pallet_seq",sequenceName = "pallet",initialValue = 1,allocationSize = 1)
   //@JsonIgnore
    private Long idPallet;
    private int maxPallet;
    private String typePallet;
    private String shipAddress;
    private String shipLocation;
    private String shipCountry;
    private String destination;
    private List<PS> PackingSlip;
}
```

*PalletController*

```
@PostMapping("/pallets")
    public void savePallet(@RequestBody Pallet pallet) {
        palletRepo.save(pallet);
    }
```

*Repository*

```
package com.example.ShippingTest.repositories;

import com.example.ShippingTest.collections.Pallet;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PalletRepo extends MongoRepository<Pallet,Long> {
    public Pallet findOrderByidPallet(Long idPallet);
}
```

whenever I try to post a new Pallet, this Exception get displayed:
"message": "Cannot autogenerate id of type java.lang.Long for entity of type com.example.ShippingTest.collections.Pallet",

I tried this without @SequenceGenerator, and even after using it, the post didn't work.
when I add @Entity in Pallet.java I get error with obligation of adding another id: 'Basic' attribute type should not be a container.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing `@Entity` annotation.

Comment: when I add @Entity in Pallet.java I get error with obligation of adding another id: 'Basic' attribute type should not be a container.

Comment: That is a relation exception
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059451/cannot-declare-list-property-in-the-jpa-entity-class-it-says-basic-attribute

Comment: id advise you to open a new question and share your entities with relations between them

Answer (score 0):

Based on MongoDB documentation: `The default value ObjectId is ideal for the auto-generated _id.`

In order to map the **ObjectId** in your POJO, you will need to define your Id a **String** object instead of Long, in order to get it auto-generated.

https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment