# Spring Boot UserDetails getAuthorities() 'Basic' attribute type should not be a container

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a parent class for each **@Entity**:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Entity() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and child class:

```
@jakarta.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Entity implements UserDetails {
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public User() {}

    public User(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // getters and setters & UserDetails override methods
    
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get an error in **getAuthorities()** method:

*'Basic' attribute type should not be a container*

When I remove inheritance and add an **@Id** directly in **User** entity, there is no error.
In other entities (without **UserDetails**) there is also no error.

Any ideas how to solve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot declare List property in the JPA @Entity class. It says 'Basic' attribute type should not be a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059451/cannot-declare-list-property-in-the-jpa-entity-class-it-says-basic-attribute)